# How to archive a Swift Project with a custom framework

Tags: xcode, swift, frameworks, bitcode

I created a custom framework and imported it into my swift project.

I have been able to run the project on my phone no problems what so ever, I have now come to build it to share on "testfairy", so 'archive' it.

When I do this I get the following error

> ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

In the framework project I have got enable bit code enabled but I can't get rid of the above error, does anyone have any suggestions?